# input reveal after first one filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to reveald a secon input in a form after the first input has been filled? For example if I have a text input asking how many kids are going on the trip, person responds and a second input appears asking age range...

Comment: Of course it is; what have you tried?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: <input class="form-control" name="ninos" type="text" id="ninos">

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xf9yzhz1/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<input id="in1" type="text" /><br>
<input id="in2" type="text" /><br>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('#in1').change(function(){
    if ( this.value != '' ) $('#in2').show().focus();
});
```

---

**Update:**

Note that you must wrap the jQuery code in a `document.ready` wrapper:

```
$(document).ready({
    $('#in1').change(function(){
        if ( this.value != '' ) $('#in2').show().focus();
    });
}); //END document.ready
```

This prevents the javascript from attempting to bind an event (the `change` event) to a DOM element (the `#in1` element) before that element exists in the DOM.  ***`$(document).ready()` ensures the DOM has been fully rendered before attempting to create the event bindings.***

Usually, all *(or almost all)* of your javascript/jQuery code is written within the `$(document).ready()` wrapper.

---

Notes:

The above code example uses jQuery, so you should reference the jQuery library in the `<head>` tags, comme ca:

```
<head>
    <!-- other stuff in head -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

*Note that if you use a CDN to load the jQuery library, as above, it is likely that jQuery is already pre-loaded from other websites visited previously.*

---

If you want some fast lessons on jQuery, find free video tuts here:

https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32

or at

http://phpacademy.org

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried but it didnt work, heres my html:   `<input class="form-control" name="ninos" type="text" id="ninos">`  `<input class="form-control" name="edades" type="text" id="edades">`   js:  `$('#ninos').change(function(){ if ( this.value != '' ) $('#edades').show().focus(); });`

Comment: I dont know how to break lines here, sorry

Comment: Yes, that should work.  Are you loading the jQuery library?  Oh, wait -- this might be it -- are you wrapping your code in a `$(document).ready()` wrapper?  **See updated answer.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You should look at either [JavaScripts `onchange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) or [jQuery's `.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event to control this action. And then of course hiding and showing certain elements.